# Is it true that all algebraic irrationals have random decimal digits/blocks?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a decimal representation of an algebraic irrational,if we consecutively choose consecutive blocks of numbers/digits. Is it true that we form a sequence of random numbers?

Comment: _Random_ is not a good choice of word here. Would you say the decimal digits of $\sqrt{2}$ form a sequence of random numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The notion you're looking for is that of a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).

[There are irrational numbers that are not normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Non-normal_numbers).
However, these are transcendental.

No algebraic number has been proven to be normal in any base.

So I guess your question is an open question.

Comment: Are these algebraic?

Comment: No, sorry. I missed that part. See my edited answer.

Comment: Borel conjectured that *all algebraic irrationals are (absolutely) normal*, but there is still no proof nor disproof of this. Re: Borel, Emile (1950), Sur les chiﬀres d´ecimaux de √2 et divers probl`emes de probabilit´es en chaˆınes, C. R. Acad. Sci., Paris 230, 591-593. (Your 2nd & 3rd sentences seem to say it's known that non-normal irrationals are necessarily transcendental.)

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture that all "real algebraic irrational numbers are normal" is a major unsolved problem. However surprisingly we have the following result which can be referenced [here](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2007/165-2/p04).